# C# Unit Test Visual Studio 2013 Test Failed

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I wrote a class Complex and class for unit tests. When the + operator performs tests crashes my error. Why?

Complex:

```
    private double re,im;

    public Complex(double re = 0.0, double im = 0.0)
    {
        this.re = re;
        this.im = im;
    }

    public static Complex operator +(Complex C1, Complex C2)
    {

        return new Complex(C1.re+C2.re,C1.im+C2.im);
    }
```

Unit test:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void ComplexPlus()
    {
        Complex c1 = new Complex(4.6, 1.6), c2 = new Complex(6.63, 2.67);
        Complex c3 = c1 + c2;
        Complex c4 =  new Complex(11.23, 4.27);
        Assert.AreEqual(c3,c4 );
    }
}
```

Comment: _"crashes my error"_ Can you be a bit more specific? I doubt anything is _crashing_ but perhaps you get an error or even perhaps just a failing test?

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if something is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are call AreEqual to the both classes Complex. You should check if their **properties** are equal !

Here is the code which you need.

```
Assert.AreEqual(c3.Re,c4.Re);
Assert.AreEqual(c3.Im,c4.Im);
```

EDIT: **Add properties**

```
private double _re, _im;

public Complex(double re = 0.0, double im = 0.0)
{
    _re = re;
    _im = im;
}

public double Re
{
     get { return _re; }
     set { _re = value; }//or just get !
}

public double Im
{
     get { return _re; }
     set { _re = value; }//or just get !
}
```

And the check will be this.

```
Assert.AreEqual(c3.Re,c4.Re);
Assert.AreEqual(c3.Im,c4.Im);
```

Comment: to do that I have to change the access to im and re to the public, it probably is not a good method?

Comment: I gets this Error 1 'Project1.Complex' does not contain a definition for 'Re' and no extension method 'Re' accepting a first argument of type 'Project1.Complex' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) in Assert.AreEqual(c3.Re, c4.Re);

Comment: @Aquena do you add public properties in the class Complex ?!

Comment: Yes - public double Re
        {
            get { return re; }
        }

        public double Im
        {
            get { return im; }
        }

Comment: It's probably because I work in 2 project on 1 solution, but I don't know how fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It's look your declared the same class in 2 projects.
Delete one and add reference from one project to other (add reference to base project to test project).

Comment: I did that, 1 solution , 2 project (1 - Project1 with class Complex, 2 - UnitTest with references to Project1). I can use class Complex ( create object etc.), but I can't use properties - 
        public double Re { get { return re; } set; }
        public double Im { get { return im; } set; } 
Why?

Comment: I think that your base project does not compile, look at the method set (not autoproperty).